# PHP - XML Parser Error

Tags: php, xml

I am sending the XML feed to Amazon with PHP.

Here is the XSD https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_1_9/amzn-base.xsd

My XMl feed throws and error when there is a decimal place Example `Volts: 6` works but `Volts: 6.50`throws an integer error,

**Full XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
                <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
                    <Header>
                        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
                        <MerchantIdentifier>ssss</MerchantIdentifier>
                    </Header>
                    <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
                    <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
                    <Message>

                        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
                        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
                        <Product>
                            <SKU>AZ-040T-2</SKU>
                            <Condition>
                                <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
                            </Condition>
                            <DescriptionData>
                                <Title>Replacement For Asss</Title>
                                <Brand>ABC</Brand>
                                <Description>Replacement For  Light Bulb&amp;lt;br&amp;gt;6.50&amp;lt;br&amp;gt;17.88&amp;lt;br&amp;gt;125</Description>
                                 <BulletPoint>Replacement For Light Bulb</BulletPoint><BulletPoint>Volts: 6.50</BulletPoint><BulletPoint>Watts: 17.88</BulletPoint>
                                <Manufacturer>Technical Precision</Manufacturer>
                                <MfrPartNumber>501</MfrPartNumber>
                                <ItemType>light-bulbs</ItemType>
                            </DescriptionData>
                            <ProductData>
                                <Lighting>
                                    <ProductType>
                                        <LightBulbs>
                                            <BulbType>Incandescent</BulbType><BulbWattage>17.88</BulbWattage><Voltage>7</Voltage></LightBulbs>
                                    </ProductType>
                                </Lighting>
                            </ProductData>
                        </Product>
                   </Message>
                   </AmazonEnvelope>
```

**Error on this line**

```
 <BulletPoint>Replacement For AIT 501 Replacement Light Bulb</BulletPoint><BulletPoint>Volts: 6.50</BulletPoint><BulletPoint>Watts: 17.88</BulletPoint>
```

**Error**

> XML Parsing Error at Line 281263, Column 133:
>   cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '6.50' is not a valid value for 'integer'.

Comment: seems obvious enough: `not a valid value for 'integer'`. The xml dtd only allows integers, and you're sending a float.

Comment: @MarcB It is a bullet point, so it should accept all integers

Comment: What a parser you use? show us  your  code

Comment: @splash58 I am updating the full XML in a min

Comment: i see - you are sending this xml to Amazon and this is an answer. Am I right?

Comment: @splash58 Yes thats the XML

Comment: I'm about error. If it comes from Amazon than, maybe, you ask support? Because your xml seems fine